# Axios interceptor is not returning to login screen when token is expired

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to write a response interceptor for my React project but I am having some issues.

When a user gets a 401 from their original request I want to try and refresh the token and continue, but if the user gets a 401 from their original request and when trying to refresh the token it fails then redirect them to the login page.

What I have does the first bit just fine, it refreshes the token and continues with the original request, but the issue i am having is that if the refresh fails, its not redirecting the user to the login page.

I would love some input on what I am doing wrong

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const router = useRouter();

const apiInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.API_URL
});

apiInstance.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
    return response;
}, async function (error) {
    const originalRequest = error.config;

    if (error.response.status === 401 && originalRequest.url === '/oauth/token') {
        router.push('/');
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }

    if (error.response.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
        originalRequest._retry = true;

        return axios.post(process.env.OAUTH_BASE_URL + '/oauth/token', {
            'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
            'refresh_token': localStorage.getItem('refresh_token'),
            'client_id': process.env.CLIENT_ID,
        })
        .then(res => {
            if (res.status === 200) {
                localStorage.setItem('access_token', res.access_token);
                localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', res.refresh_token);
                localStorage.setItem('expires_in', res.expires_in);

                axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token');

                return apiInstance(originalRequest);
            }
        })
    }

    return Promise.reject(error);
});

export default apiInstance;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of errors here. First, `url` property is equal to the whole value of `url` param of axios call, so this...

```
originalRequest.url === '/oauth/token'
```

... is only true if `process.env.OAUTH_BASE_URL` is an empty string (and most likely it's not). In general, it's better to avoid checking against URLs and use flags/custom properties set on request objects (as with _retry flag).

Also, note that while `apiInstance` is used for regular API call, the particular call for refresh token actually avoids it:

```
return axios.post(process.env.OAUTH_BASE_URL + '/oauth/token', { // 
       ^^^^^^^^^^
```

... which means interceptors for this call are not even fired.

---

Here's one possible approach to solve this. `apiInstance` here is the exported axios instance, and `setTokens`/`getAccessToken`/`getRefreshToken` are simple abstractions over mechanisms of storing/retrieving particular tokens.

```
apiInstance.interceptors.request.use(request => {
  if (!request._refreshToken) {
    request.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + getAccessToken();
  }
  // console.log('REQUEST', request.method + ' ' + request.url);
  return request;
});

apiInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  void 0, // better skip this argument altogether
  error => {
    const originalRequest = error.config;
    if (originalRequest._refreshToken) {
      console.log('REFRESH TOKEN FAILED');
      // ... and all the things you need to do when refreshing token failed,
      // like resettting access token, and rerouting users to /login page,
      // or just sending an event for Router to process

      return Promise.reject(error);
    }

    const errorResponse = error.response;
    if (errorResponse.status !== 401) {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }

    return apiInstance.post('/oauth/token', {
      grant_type: 'refresh_token',
      refresh_token: getRefreshToken(), 
      client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    }, {
      _refreshToken: true // custom parameter
    }).then((resp) => {
      setTokens(resp.data);
      return apiInstance(originalRequest);
    });
  }
);
```

There are two ideas behind this (easily testable with unit tests): first, failed refresh token requests *always* stop the interceptor chain (as they throw immediately), second, if 'business-level' API request fails, it's always preceded with refresh-token one.

Note that this code is just a prototype to illustrate the concept here. If you expect your code to be able to issue multiple API calls at once, token refresh should actually be wrapped into a function returning single promise (to avoid subsequent refresh-token calls). If you're going to use this in production, I strongly suggest at least considering using [axios-auth-refresh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-auth-refresh) instead of writing your own implementation for that.

Comment: This is my first time at a interceptor, im still learning

Comment: I added the base url, but that didnt work wither

Comment: Can you debug your code and make sure that either of two things is true: execution does or doesn't go inside that `if` branch?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be entering the if statement at all but in console it is showing that URL with a 401 which is weird

Comment: It seems the `originalRequest.url` is only showing the `/page` which i was going to, not the url of the refresh url

Comment: Could you reorganize your code to have if branch that definitely gets entered on failed `/oauth/token` call, then check error.response.status there; perhaps the code is not 401 there?

Comment: @CodeSauce Makes sense actually, so axios doesn't treat interceptor call separately. One more case for setting up a flag (like `originalRequest._refreshToken = true` or something).

Comment: Is there any chance you could show an example of what you mean by the flag? Im a little confused

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228987/discussion-between-raina77ow-and-codesauce).